# iTunes NOT Using Gift Cards on File

Tags: itunes

I have as my iTunes balance around $52. When my son, using the Family Share program, requests to purchase a song and I approve, it is bypassing the Gift Card balance and charging my credit card.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's "[How iTunes Store purchases are billed](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201359)":

> ***How are Family Sharing purchases billed?*** When you initiate a new purchase, it will be billed directly to the family organizer's
>   account, unless you have gift or store credit. First, your store
>   credit will be used to pay the partial or total bill. The remainder
>   will bill to the family organizer. iTunes Store credit on your account
>   isn't shared with other family members. **So if the family organizer has
>   a $50 credit on their account and another family member initiates a
>   purchase, it won't deduct from the organizer's iTunes Store credit,
>   but will bill the organizer's credit or debit card.** The family
>   organizer will get the receipts for any of their family member's
>   purchases.

More important legal verbiage about the iTunes Store at [this link](http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/us/terms.html).

Comment: IconDaemon, My billing is set up for Credit Card charging. However, my sons got gift cards for Christmas. We loaded the gift cards and now when they purchase something, I am getting an email from Apple and it says it is charging to my MC. I can click on my name in iTunes and see my gift card balance. Shouldn't the GC be exhausted before charing my CC? Thanks!

Comment: "iTunes Store credit on your account isn't shared with other family members." Your son would have had to cash in his iTunes Store cards to his **own** iTunes Store account to be able to purchase stuff. Because your credit card is tied to the family organizer account, and no family member can use iTunes store credit, **you**, (and only you,) can use the monies imported through gift cards.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  It seems you need to redeem iTunes gift cards on the child's device NOT your computer or device. In other words whichever Apple ID you use to redeem the gift card is who can use it.   You have to go into iTunes Store on the device you want to use the gift card and use the redeem function.